# How do I change the layout of text areas in java swing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jtextarea

I started making this web page for a project and this is what it looks like so far:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzsKS.png]

but I want to place the text areas as one on top of the other rather than side to side

How i want it to look:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHrgS.png]

can someone help me out please

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzsKS.png

Comment: The default layout for a JPanel is the FlowLayout which is why you see the components on a line. If you want a different layout then you need to use a different layout manager. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples. Maybe use a GridBagLayout?

Comment: Why are you using Java Swing to create a web page?

Answer (score -1):

Set the layout of your panel (or whatever component that contains your textareas) to GridLayout with 4 rows and 1 column. This will put all 4 components (2 Labels and 2 TextAreas one after another in a column)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

Comment: GridLayout is the wrong choice for this.  It will force each label to be the same size as each JTextArea.